# How to use DbFunction translation in EF Core?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core, full-text-search

I'm looking for something like `EF.Functions.FreeText` that was implemented in SQL Server but using the `MATCH...AGAINST` syntax of MySQL.

This is my current workflow:
AspNetCore 2.1.1
EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.4
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 2.1.4

The problem is that MySQL uses two functions and I don't know how to interpret that with `DbFunction` and separate the arguments for each one. Does anyone know how to implement this?

This should be the Linq syntax:

```cs
query.Where(x => DbContext.FullText(new[] { x.Col1, x.Col2, x.Col3 }, "keywords"));
```

And this should be the result generated in SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM t WHERE MATCH(`Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`) AGAINST('keywords');
```

I'm trying to follow the following examples using the `HasTranslation` function:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11295#issuecomment-511440395
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10241#issuecomment-342989770

*Note: I know it can be solved with `FromSql`, but it's not what I'm looking for.*

Comment: What would be the signature of the method in question?

Comment: We can follow the same design pattern that they use in [EF Core](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/f8ee688bb87ac6d3551a39654571c50db63f4765/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Extensions/SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions.cs#L49), but using an array to accept multiple properties, something like this `public static bool FullText(string[] propertyReferences, string fullText)`

Comment: The problem is that unfortunately currently `new [] { … }` is not supported inside expressions, so our translation won't be called at all. And unfortunately you can't create the array outside the query because you need access to `x` from `x =>`. Creating a function with several overloads `(string, string)`, `(string, string, string)`, `(string, string, string, string)` etc. though is relatively easy.  Let me know if that works for you. Because handling `new [] {… }` argument will require pugging deeply into EF Core infrastructure.

Answer (score 7):

Your use case is very similar to mine when I needed [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) support in EF Core.

Example:

```
// gets translated to
// ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY OrderId, Count)
DbContext.OrderItems.Select(o => new {
  RowNumber = EF.Functions.RowNumber(o.ProductId, new {
    o.OrderId,
    o.Count
  })
})
```

**Use anonymous classes instead of arrays**

The first thing you have to do is to switch from using an array to an anonymous class, i.e. you change the call from

`DbContext.FullText(new[] { x.Col1, x.Col2, x.Col3 }, "keywords")`

to

`DbContext.FullText(new { x.Col1, x.Col2, x.Col3 }, "keywords")`

The sort order of the parameters will stay as it is defined by in the query, 
i.e `new { x.Col1, x.Col2 }` will be translated to `Col1, Col2`
and `new { x.Col2, x.Col1 }` to `Col2, Col1`.

You can even to the following: `new { x.Col1, _ = x.Col1, Foo = "bar" }` that is going to be translated to `Col1, Col1, 'bar'`.

**Implement custom `IMethodCallTranslator`**

If you need some hints then you can look through my code on [Azure DevOps: RowNumber Support](https://dev.azure.com/pawelgerr/Thinktecture.EntityFrameworkCore/_wiki/wikis/Thinktecture.EntityFrameworkCore.wiki?pagePath=%2FFeatures%2FRowNumber%20Support&pageId=14&wikiVersion=GBwikiMaster) or if you can wait a few days then I will provide a blog post about the implementation of custom functions.

**Updated (31 july, 2019)**

Blog posts:

- [Entity Framework Core: Custom Functions (using IMethodCallTranslator)](https://weblogs.thinktecture.com/pawel/2019/07/entity-framework-core-custom-functions-using-imethodcalltranslator.html)
- [Entity Framework Core: Custom Functions (using HasDbFunction)](https://weblogs.thinktecture.com/pawel/2019/07/entity-framework-core-custom-functions-using-hasdbfunction.html)

**Updated (july 27, 2019)**

Thanks to the comments below I see that some clarification is required.

**1)** As pointed out in the comment below there is another approach. With `HasDbFunction` I could save me some typing like the code for registration of the translator with EF but I would still need the `RowNumberExpression` because the function has 2 sets of parameters (for `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY`) and the existing `SqlFunctionExpression` doesn't support that. (or did I missed something?) The reason I've chosen the approach with `IMethodCallTranslator` is because I want the configuration of this feature to be done during setting up of the `DbContextOptionsBuilder` and not in `OnModelCreating`. That is, it’s a personal preference of mine.

In the end the thread creator can use `HasDbFunction` to implement the desired feature as well. In my case the code would look something like the following:

```
// OnModelCreating
  var methodInfo = typeof(DemoDbContext).GetMethod(nameof(DemoRowNumber));

  modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(methodInfo)
            .HasTranslation(expressions => {
                 var partitionBy = (Expression[])((ConstantExpression)expressions.First()).Value;
                 var orderBy = (Expression[])((ConstantExpression)expressions.Skip(1).First()).Value;

                 return new RowNumberExpression(partitionBy, orderBy);
});

// the usage with this approach is identical to my current approach
.Select(c => new {
    RowNumber = DemoDbContext.DemoRowNumber(
                                  new { c.Id },
                                  new { c.RowVersion })
    })
```

**2)** An anonymous type can’t enforce the type(s) of its members, so you can get a runtime exception if the function is called with, say, `integer` instead of `string`. Still, it can be valid solution. Depending on the customer you are working for the solution may be more or less viable, in the end the decision lies with the customer. Not providing any alternatives is a possible solution as well but not a satisfying one. 
Especially, if the usage of SQL is not desired (because you get even less support from compiler) so the runtime exception may be a good compromise after all.

But, if the compromise is still not acceptable then we can make a research on how to add support for arrays. 
First approach could be the implementation of a custom `IExpressionFragmentTranslator` to “redirect” the handling of arrays to us.

> Please note, it is just a prototype and needs more investigation/testing :-)

```
// to get into EF pipeline
public class DemoArrayTranslator : IExpressionFragmentTranslator
{
    public Expression Translate(Expression expression)
    {
       if (expression?.NodeType == ExpressionType.NewArrayInit)
       {
          var arrayInit = (NewArrayExpression)expression;
          return new DemoArrayInitExpression(arrayInit.Type, arrayInit.Expressions);
       }

       return null;
    }
}

// lets visitors visit the array-elements
public class DemoArrayInitExpression : Expression
{
   private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> _expressions;

   public override Type Type { get; }
   public override ExpressionType NodeType => ExpressionType.Extension;

   public DemoArrayInitExpression(Type type, 
           ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> expressions)
   {
      Type = type ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
      _expressions = expressions ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expressions));
   }

   protected override Expression Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   {
      var visitedExpression = visitor.Visit(_expressions);
      return NewArrayInit(Type.GetElementType(), visitedExpression);
   }
}

// adds our DemoArrayTranslator to the others
public class DemoRelationalCompositeExpressionFragmentTranslator 
      : RelationalCompositeExpressionFragmentTranslator
{
    public DemoRelationalCompositeExpressionFragmentTranslator(
             RelationalCompositeExpressionFragmentTranslatorDependencies dependencies)
         : base(dependencies)
      {
         AddTranslators(new[] { new DemoArrayTranslator() });
      }
   }

// Register the translator
services
  .AddDbContext<DemoDbContext>(builder => builder
       .ReplaceService<IExpressionFragmentTranslator,
                       DemoRelationalCompositeExpressionFragmentTranslator>());
```

For testing I introduced another overload containing `Guid[]` as parameter.
*Although, this method doesn't make sense in my use case at all :)*

```
public static long RowNumber(this DbFunctions _, Guid[] orderBy)
```

And adjusted the usage of the method

```
// Translates to ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id)
.Select(c => new { 
                RowNumber = EF.Functions.RowNumber(new Guid[] { c.Id })
})
```

Comment: Good attempt, but... (1) Overcomplicated. Too much plumbing code for adding simple method. If the method does not require custom expressions, `HasDbFunction` + `HasTranslation` should be enough. (2) `new { x.Col1, x.Col2, x.Col3 }` is not the same as `new string[] { x.Col1, x.Col2, x.Col3 }` - the later is compile time safe while the former is not (does not enforce that all the members are `string` type). I understand why you suggest that, but most of the people reading won't - a type unsafe workaround for current EF Core method argument translation lack of `new T[] { ... }` support.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank your for comments, they brought me some ideas! I've added a few sections to my original answer.

Comment: Added links to blog posts about implementation of custom functions.

Comment: I tried to implement it but it was very complicated for me, do you think you can help me to implement it?

Comment: Hi @PawelGerr - I've been banging my head against the wall trying to get EF.Functions.RowNumber to play nice with my ASP.NET Core 3.1 project, but I consistently get the "This method is for use with Entity Framework Core only and has no in-memory implementation." error despite having added .AddRowNumberSupport() after .UseSqlServer in my Startup.cs.

Specifically, trying to select the following directly from the LatestEmpireEntries DbSet:
RowNumber = EF.Functions.RowNumber(EF.Functions.OrderBy(o.EmpireId))

Comment: @JohannSig are you using the version 2.0.0-beta004 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Thinktecture.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/) ?
if yes and you have some issue then you can file an issue in devops:
https://dev.azure.com/pawelgerr/Thinktecture.EntityFrameworkCore/_wiki/wikis/Thinktecture.EntityFrameworkCore.wiki/14/RowNumber-Support

Comment: @Pawel Gerr, Unfortunately, I cannot use the Thinktecture Nuget package due to my company restrictions. How ever, I am trying to implement the row number with partition by using the approach mentioned above. I am facing issue in extracting the partition by and order by information. I am getting the argument information in the form of SQL expression. Also can you please tell me what is the sample method signature used.

I am using .net core 3.1 and ef core 3.1